# How to set ng-class equal to some value in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a list where I want to assign some class, like `items-count-1`, `items-count-2`, `items-count-3`, `items-count-4`, depending on the total number of items in the list.

I want to have something looking like this:

```
li(ng-repeat="area in areas", ng-class="items-count-{areas.length}")
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here: [plnkr example](http://embed.plnkr.co/29FtYtwiaw9woMSetHkO/preview)

In short, you want your ng-class set as this:

```
ng-class="'items-count-' + areas.length"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just double braces, i. e.

```
li(ng-repeat="area in areas", ng-class="items-count-{{areas.length}}")
```